# Replace NA in all columns: argument is not numeric or logical

Tags: r

I want to loop though a lot of columns in an r dataframe and replace NA with column mean.

I can get a mean for columns like this

```
mean(df$col20, na.rm = TRUE)
```

But this gets the warning: argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

```
mean(df[ , 20], na.rm = TRUE)
```

I tried the above syntax with a small dummy df including some NA and it works fine. Any idea what else to look for to fix this?

ps. head(df[20]) tells me it's a dbl and str(df) says it's num.

(and [ , 20] is an example; I actually get lots of warnings because it really sits in a for loop - but I have executed the line by itself as a test)

Comment: A mean doesn't make sense if the column is not numeric...

Comment: If your `df` is a tibble, then subsetting it with square bracket (`[`) will return a tibble, where you cannot calculate `mean` directly on a tibble

Comment: There are characters in the columns. `mean(as.numeric(df$col20), na.rm = TRUE)` will get the right result.

Comment: If you are looping, then you can do `mean(df[[20]],na.rm=TRUE)` where `[[` _always_ returns a single column with both `tibble` and `data.frame`; it's `[`'s behavior (as benson23 astutely pointed out) that is inconsistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) na.aggregate** Create a logical vector `ok` which is TRUE for each numeric column and FALSE for other columns.  Then use `na.aggregate` on the numeric columns.

```
library(zoo)
df <- data.frame(a = c(1, NA, 2), b = c("a", NA, "b")) # test data


ok <- sapply(df, is.numeric)
replace(df, ok, na.aggregate(df[ok]))
```

giving:

```
    a    b
1 1.0    a
2 1.5 <NA>
3 2.0    b
```

**2) dplyr/tidyr** Alternately use dplyr.  `df` is from above and the output is the same.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ replace_na(., mean(., na.rm =TRUE))))
```

**3) collapse**  We could alternately use `ftransformv` in collapse.

```
library(collapse)
library(zoo)

ftransformv(df, is.numeric, na.aggregate)
```

**4) base** A base solution would be:

```
fill_na <- function(x) {
  if (!is.numeric(x) || all(is.na(x))) x
  else replace(x, is.na(x), mean(x, na.rm = TRUE))
}

replace(df, TRUE, lapply(df, fill_na))
```